# Getting data from wsdl using Soap Client using zeep

Tags: python-3.x, soap-client

I'm trying to get the data from client erp's through wsdl file in python.
for that i have[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duSpE.png)

next it's going to [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBlEz.png)

the default sale_order_id =140

and it's going for

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxXSc.png)

like that i'm trying to get the data from wsdl file

but i'm confused to get the data from the wsdl file.

please help me..

thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far? share your code with the community so they could help you